# How can I display a VNC Viewer in a Java rich client (LGPL, Apache, MIT license)?

Tags: java, open-source

I'm looking for a way to display a VNC viewer in a thick/rich java client (specifically, I'm using SWT, but if I can get it into AWT/Swing, I can integrate that specifically.)  This is not an applet, but a real, live, thick java client.

[TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html) is probably sufficient; however, its GPL license is too restrictive for my needs.

Is anyone aware of a Java VNC library available under a less restrictive license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick survey of the options thus far (I haven't found a satisfactory answer as of this writing):

- **[vncjlgpl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vncjlgpl)** - Server only.  Perhaps I could use the knowledge captured here to roll my own, which would make it a derivative work, which could be LGPL'd.
- **[TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com)** - Provides a Java-based viewer.  I haven't looked at the source yet, but I'm assuming it could be reused suitably.  However; it's GPL license prevents reuse in my pseudo-commerical product.
- **[RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/support/javavncviewer.html)** - Provides a Java application that is a VNC viewer.  Commerical product.  No source available.  A publicly available installation of the .jar (launchable via webstart) is [here](http://danielwebb.us/software/vnc/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need something for this, but I've found the MetaVNC (on sourceforge) java viewer is pretty simple to work with. Last mods were in 2007 so it doesn't look like it's being maintained, but it might give you basic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vncjlgpl, possibly?

Edit: never mind, that's a server only. I got distracted when I clicked the wrong link.